# EC2 Instance running Glue Script causing Connection Timeout Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

Running into a strange issue on our EC2 instance. We have Glue Jobs scheduled and were running on a Glue DEV endpoint successfully last Friday via EC2. Recently we are running into the below error from Ec2:

```
connection timeout on endpoint URL: https://glue.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/
```

We have verified the following:
VPC, Route Tables, CIDMs, Subnets have not changed. GLUE DEV endpoints have not been modified. Glue Jobs/Scripts remain the same. EC2 config has not changed.

Any advice is appreciated, this has been troubling our team for a few days now.

Comment: any changes in the inbound/outbound rules in security groups attached to EC2 and Dev Endpoint?

Comment: @HarshBafna Nothing has changed in the Inbound / Outbound rules for the EC2 or Dev Endpoints